# input fields keeping the same information entered previously

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm working on a web development assignment and i'm a little stuck, so i have 2 pages, the first one is formulaire.html which contains a form that sends informations to my second page which is recap.php, and in that page i have a button that must send me back to the form page with all the informations entered previously still there, i can't use any php in the first page it must remain .html, i was thinking of creating a modify.js file but i would have to get my $_SESSION variables in it, which i don't know if it's possible, if anyone can help me out it'd be great.

Comment: Show your code. Thats what we read here. Your description in text is cool but on same token you yourself admit that things are going wrong. Only source code will reveal the errors. If you could update your post with your source code it would be highly productive in someone finding the bug.

Comment: i don't have a bug because i'm still thinking of a way to do it, i didn't make an attempt, because i have no clue what to do, i'm just looking for guidance.

Comment: *so i have 2 pages* .. show these, the relevant parts. And include your theory of what u need to do. I'd recommend *you* testing your theory out. Wouldn't hurt. .... *i'm just looking for guidance* again show your code, guidance can only come if there is something to guide by. If you are looking for sample code then there is the "internet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to use localStorage in javascript???

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
var key = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208166/discussion-on-answer-by-abdelazeez-mabrouk-input-fields-keeping-the-same-informa).